# Haskell record syntax error: not in scope

Tags: haskell, types, record

I am trying to define a multi-way tree data type in ghci. Each node has a key and a value. Here is the related code:

```
    data Tree k v = Empty |
                    N {key::k,
                       value::v} [Tree k v]
                  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Here is corresponding output from Ghci:

```
    Not in scope: `key'
    Not in scope: `value'
```

I checked the syntax of the record by defining the tree node record separately using the following code:

```
   data Node k v = Node { key::k
                        , value::v}
                 deriving (Show, Eq)
```

This works as expected. What is causing my **Tree** data type definition to throw this error? Am I missing something related to record syntax when used to define an alternate value constructor?

Comment: Note that the record accessors are functions in the module scope. So `key` and `value` are now functions that might override any other definition. This is why you usually see `treeValue` instead of just `value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the record syntax with ADTs, all constructors must have the same fields.  Additionally, you're attempting to combine record and normal constructor syntax with `Node { key :: k, value :: v } [Tree k v]`.  Instead, you'll have to resort to normal positional arguments to your constructor like

```
data Tree k v
    = Emtpy
    | N k v [Tree k v]
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

---

You could use record syntax with ADTs as

```
data Tree k v
    = RedNode   { key :: k, val :: v, children :: [Tree k v] }
    | BlackNode { key :: k, val :: v, children :: [Tree k v] }
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

But I would recommend making a separate data type as

```
data Color = Red | Black deriving (Eq, Show)

data Tree k v = Node
    { color :: Color
    , key :: k
    , val :: v
    , children :: [Tree k v]
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Because then if you extend `Color`, you have less typing, and I would argue that it's more idiomatic.

Comment: Nit-pick all constructors don't have to have the same fields.  When not all fields are present on all constructors, you get accessors that are partial:

    Prelude> data Foo = Empty | One { only :: String } | More { than_ever :: [Int] }
    Prelude> :t Empty
    Empty :: Foo
    Prelude> :t One "Another"
    One "Another" :: Foo
    Prelude> :t More [2, 4]
    More [2, 4] :: Foo
    Prelude> only $ More [2, 4]
    "*** Exception: No match in record selector only
    Prelude> than_ever Empty
    *** Exception: No match in record selector than_ever

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a separate node type, you may be looking for something like

```
data Tree k v = Empty | N (Node k v) [Tree k v]
              deriving (Show, Eq)

data Node k v = Node { key::k
                     , value::v}
              deriving (Show, Eq)
```